# Some URL is giving me a blue webpage

Tags: google-chrome, html

Can anyone tell me from HTML source why I am getting blue webpage on [this](https://infinity.icicibank.co.in/BANKAWAY?Action.RetUser.Init.001=Y&AppSignonBankId=ICI&AppType=corporate&abrdPrf=N) page ?

I get this only on Chrome v17, rest all browser it works fine.

Comment: add a screenshot

Comment: Do you mean a BSOD error and computer restart or simply the webpage is blank blue?

Comment: No BSOD, the webpage is blank blue ...

Comment: Do you have QT plugin installed? That page uses QT, although it crashed on my browser (Firefox 11 Beta)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ICICI bank website uses the Apple Quicktime plugin. The plugin may not have been upgraded to the newer Chrome 17, hence the compatibility issues.

Stick to other browsers till Apple releases a newer version of the QuickTime plugin for Chrome.

Comment: Can you tell me how do you identify it uses QT ?

Comment: I have a virgin browser test box and FF/Chrome/IE asks for missing plugins. I tried the site in there and it prompted for Apple QT.